# Determine table based on prompt

Tags: business-objects, universe

PostPosted: 09 May 2014 22:26 
Post subject: Determine table based on prompt
Hello,

I have three fact tables. First table holds current data, FACT_CUSTOMER_CURRENT. Other two tables hold historical snapshots. For example, one of these table holds last 60 days' records- FACT_CUSTOMER_DAILY. The other table holds data for the last day of the months.-FACT_CUSTOMER_MONTHLY

I want to add a date prompt. If the user selects yesterday as a prompt value, report should bring value from first table which holds current data (FACT_CUSTOMER_CURRENT). If user enters 28.02.2014, the report should retrieve data from FACT_CUSTOMER_MONTHLY. I tried to use context and aggregate awareness, but I could not be successful. 
Can you help me?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

There's no direct, easy way to do what you want.

Aggregate Awareness is useful for selecting a table based on the selection of objects in a query, but it does not support dynamic selection of tables based on values in a prompt.

If yesterday's data will **only** exist in `fact_customer_current`, then you can use this method: In your report, create a UNION query.  One query includes objects from `fact_customer_current`, and the other from `fact_customer_monthly`.  They both have an identical prompt on the appropriate date field.  When a user enters yesterday's date, the first UNION query will return data but the second one won't.  Likewise for date before yesterday, the first UNION will return no data but the second one will.  This solution requires that the tables are correctly indexed such that a query on a date that isn't in the table will return quickly.